# getting jquery object after bind(this) in react componentDidMount

Tags: jquery, reactjs

In my application, I'm using a 3rd party plugin in componentDidMound, something that'd look like this:

```
clickStuff: function () {
    //do stuff
},
componentDidMount: function () {

    $(".whatever").on { 'click', function() {
         this.clickStuff();
     }.bind(this));
 }
```

This allows it where if I click any div with class "whatever" to go to the react function "clickStuff()";

But what if I wanted to get "this" jquery node. Like the properties of $(".whatever") ? For example:

```
componentDidMount: function () {

    $(".whatever").on { 'click', function() {
         //this will cause conflict between the two this
         $(this).attr("title", this.state.titleMessage);
     }.bind(this));
 }
```

Where this in $(this) should be the jquery node, and the this in "this.state.titleMessage" should be the react part.

How do you get both to be part of the same function? Or do I need to do something fancy? I'm a bit confused in how to do this. I don't know what to call this problem.

Comment: to avoid any conflict with other API, you can just do jquery(this) to get the jquery object.

Comment: I see what you mean.  One is jQuery object. You could try $(this)[0] to get the node.

Comment: Getting the jquery object is fine I think for him, right? He just needs the instance of the node, same as document.getElementById(id); Unless I am incorrect on that.

Comment: when I looked at "this" in my debugging tool, "this" was completely react's object. I couldn't fetch jquery's node at all. I was hoping bind() would merge the object, so that I could do the stuff you guys are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    var that = this;
    $(".whatever").on { 'click', function() {
        //that is the this of componentDidMount (and so of clickStuff)
        that.clickStuff();
        //this remains the same
        $(this).attr("title", that.state.titleMessage);
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually did it this way before.. and it was working. I guess this is better solution that using bind :-/

Comment: JavaScript is a tricky language, keep in mind the "new ways" (bind is not so new anymore though) and the old ways ;-)